# Log4net not logging any errors

Tags: log4net

Ive added a log4net implementation to my project but it isnt logging anything at all

In my web.config

```
<log4net>

    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
      <file value="C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Onboarding\\data\\logs\\log.{date}.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
      </layout>
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
       <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
       <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG" />
       <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
   </filter>
    </appender>

  </log4net>
```

In my global.asax:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

In the class (at the class level) where I log the error

```
ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase
                                                 .GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

and then in the method itself:

```
_logger.Log(AusSuperOnboarding.Business.Logging.Enum.Level.Fatal,
            GetType().Name, "Exception thrown in SendMessage()", null);
```

Comment: Are you **completely** sure Global.asax is firing? **Put a throw new exception in there** for test and check (do **not** use debugger/breakpoints)

Answer (score 1):

Makes sure the service account user that the web site code runs with has a write access to the path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Onboarding\data\logs

If you are using IIS web site, you can check the application pool associated with the site and then right click on the app pool and choose advanced settings, you can see the app pool identity in the Identity field.

View the properties of the log folder, Choose Security tab, click Edit and add the app pool identity user and make sure the "Modify" check box is ticked

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is incomplete.

You have defined appenders, but no loggers to use them. This means when you create a logger, it has no appenders associated with it, and thus no logging is done.

Add a `root` element to your config: as log4net loggers are hierarchical, any loggers you create will all inherit the appenders from it:

```
<root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
<root>
```

Comment: This wasn't exactly my problem, but it pointed me in the right direction.  I had a console logger and filelogger in the <root> element.  It worked locally during testing, but in production, it didn't work until I removed the console log appender - maybe this will help someone else :)